# How do you track down slow tls handshake in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl

Recently we've added more users to our system and although the bandwidth usage is still in normal bounds and and server response is in normal bounds (after the tls handshake), the tls handshake can take between 1 and 2.5 seconds.  Here the time between client hello and server hello was 1.5 seconds:

```
13:01:49.599739 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
13:01:51.023274 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
```

We're running nodejs 16 with greenlock-express (I don't think that express or greenlock has anything to do with the handshake).  Anyone have any ideas on how to find what's causing slow handshake? I noticed that after pm2 restart on the process the handshake is quick (at first), but I don't have any ideas as to why this should be:

```
13:20:24.977793 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
13:20:25.063494 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
```

If we look at the whole log besides the delay between client and server hello - things are running smoothly.

```
:~$ curl -iv  --trace-time https://{server name}
13:01:49.496453 * Rebuilt URL to: https://{server name}/
13:01:49.500927 *   Trying 54.73.36.16...
13:01:49.500970 * TCP_NODELAY set
13:01:49.583976 * Connected to {server name} (54.73.36.16) port 443 (#0)
13:01:49.585712 * ALPN, offering h2
13:01:49.585791 * ALPN, offering http/1.1
13:01:49.599251 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
13:01:49.599324 *   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
13:01:49.599739 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
13:01:51.023274 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
13:01:51.023566 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
13:01:51.023602 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
13:01:51.023679 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
13:01:51.023764 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
13:01:51.024257 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
13:01:51.024312 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
13:01:51.024439 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
13:01:51.024504 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
13:01:51.024599 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
13:01:51.024708 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
13:01:51.024785 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
13:01:51.024902 * SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
13:01:51.024957 * ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
13:01:51.025023 * Server certificate:
13:01:51.025089 *  subject: CN={server name}
13:01:51.025143 *  start date: Oct 10 07:55:03 2022 GMT
13:01:51.025205 *  expire date: Jan  8 07:55:02 2023 GMT
13:01:51.025273 *  subjectAltName: host "{server name}" matched cert's "{server name}"
13:01:51.025341 *  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
13:01:51.025402 *  SSL certificate verify ok.
13:01:51.025490 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
13:01:51.025584 > GET / HTTP/1.1
13:01:51.025584 > Host: {server name}
13:01:51.025584 > User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
13:01:51.025584 > Accept: */*
13:01:51.025584 >
13:01:51.139620 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
13:01:51.139776 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
13:01:51.139981 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
13:01:51.140130 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
13:01:51.221629 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
13:01:51.221752 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
13:01:51.221934 < X-Powered-By: Express
X-Powered-By: Express
13:01:51.222112 < Vary: Origin
Vary: Origin
13:01:51.222265 < Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
13:01:51.222428 < Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
13:01:51.222564 < Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Nov 2022 13:14:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Nov 2022 13:14:39 GMT
13:01:51.222687 < ETag: W/"403-1847120b218"
ETag: W/"403-1847120b218"
13:01:51.222811 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
13:01:51.222946 < Content-Length: 1027
Content-Length: 1027
13:01:51.223068 < Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AD0KBzxmVDIb8vYcBmtdTZ6bvRF17NT1Q.1c6pkFHEoNWHl%2F4OT6bqMkm1csE; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AD0KBzxmVDIb8vYcBmtdTZ6bvRF17NT1Q.1c6pkFHEoNWbqMkm1csE; Path=/; HttpOnly
13:01:51.223192 < Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2022 11:01:50 GMT
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2022 11:01:50 GMT
13:01:51.223316 < Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
13:01:51.223439 < Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

13:01:51.223567 <
<!doctype html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end there was no problem with the tls handshake...
Our problem was because of a large session database. The session manager demanded a lot of cpu for this (which stole the cpu away from other things like crypto).

We noticed this when running the a cpu profile in the chrome dev tools while running the server in --inspect.  I decided to answer this question instead of deleting in case someone else comes cross the same thing.  If you come across a problem in the tls handshake - then take a look at what's grabbing the cpu.  In our case after we cleared out the session database, the handshake became consistently quick.

[image: cpu profiler]